# Soil Moisture Sensor Power Issues

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage, power, low-power

I'm working with some capacitive soil moisture sensors ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07SYBSHGX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SYBSHGX)) for a project and I'm having difficulty powering them off my power supply ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08JYPMCZY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JYPMCZY)). The sensors are advertised as working "3.3 ~ 5.5 VDC" but they don't work at all when connected to this power supply. I've confirmed that that they work perfectly when connected to the 5.5V or 3.3V pins on my Arduino Uno. According to my multimeter, my power supplies are providing between 4.95 and 4.99V to the sensors while the Arduino provides 5.01V (with similar differences for the 3.3V mode).

My main question is whether this tiny difference in voltage is the issue or if I'm missing something else? I'm new at this so it's probably something obvious but this one's really stumping me. Additionally, are there any solutions besides just powering all of the moisture sensors through the Arduino?

Comment: Did you remember to connect the ground from the sensor to the ground of the Arduino?  Without that, the Arduino will not be able to read the output voltage.

Comment: Please draw a schematic of how you connected everything.

Comment: @JRE That fixed it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to connect the ground pin on the arduino into the ground for the sensor (I just put them on the same breadboard ground rail). Thanks to @JRE for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

These are garbage cheap designs that use a 555 timer to measure impedance of moisture, which is 80x greater than air.

- Power sequence protection for CMOS ? For hot connection (damaged?)
- ESD protection?
- NE555 (NG) or TL555 (OK)
- poor conformal coating on electronics and connector !!,

  - needs a thick dip coating on connector and electronics-end only, and calibration compared before and after.

Might last 1 season

Comment: All good points (I conformal coated the sides of the PCB and electronics before calibrating) but I really just needed something cheap to water houseplants plants while away for a little while. Any suggestions for better quality sensors in the future?